# Add unique request ID to all application logs. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, graphql, aiohttp

I have created a unique request ID in my application and log it every time when using logger. But in order to investigate issues I want to pass that request ID to all application logs - sqlalchemy, aiohttp, graphql.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: How do you include it in your own logs? How is request scope determined? Thread/request, or are you using coroutines?

Comment: I use coroutines. I include it in every log as a variable created at the very beginning of the request includes unique data - user id and timestamp.

Comment: I think you'll find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801739/aiohttp-logging-how-to-distinguish-log-messages-of-different-requests?rq=1 useful.

Comment: Thank You for the tip. I'll try it out.